# How to position an image over <table>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, html-table

```css
#board{
    width: 94%;
    height: 94%;
    border: .4rem solid #000;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1.7%;
    background-color: green;
    border: .4rem solid #000;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1.7%;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
}

tr{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 ! important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.col{
    padding: 0 ! important;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 890;
}
.odd{
    background-color: green;
}
.even{
    background-color: #fff;
}
/*#rw-one,#rw-three,#rw-five,#rw-seven,#rw-nine{
    /*width: 100%;
    height: 100%;*//*
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: red;
}*/
table{
    border-spacing: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align:center;
}

.nmbr{
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 7px yellow;
    margin-top: 26% ! important;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 34%;
    font-family: fantasy;
}
td,tr{
    border-spacing: 0;
}

#rw-ten .nmbr{
  margin-left: 37%;
}

.lddr,.snk{
    /*position:fixed;*/
    z-index: 990;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
#lddr1{
    width: 3%;
    height: 39%;
    transform: rotate(42deg);
    margin-top: calc(2% + 308px);
    margin-left: calc(2% + 57px);
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
                        <table>
                            <tr id="rw-one">
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">100</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">99</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">98</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">97</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">96</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">95</span></td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">94</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">93</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">92</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">91</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="rw-two">
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">81</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">82</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">83</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">84</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">85</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">86</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">87</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">88</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">89</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">90</span> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="rw-three">
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">80</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">79</span></td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">78</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">77</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">76</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">75</span></td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">74</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">73</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">72</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">71</span> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="rw-four">
                                <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">61</span></td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">62</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">63</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">64</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">65</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">66</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">67</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">68</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">69</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">70</span> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="rw-five">
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">60</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">59</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">58</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">57</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">56</span></td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">55</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">54</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">53</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">52</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">51</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="rw-six">
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">41</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">42</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">43</span></td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">44</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">45</span></td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">46</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">47</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">48</span></td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">49</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">50</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="rw-seven">
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">40</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">39</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">38</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">37</span></td>
                                <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">36</span></td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">35</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">34</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">33</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">32</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">31</span> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="rw-eight">
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">21</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">22</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">23</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">24</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">25</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">26</span></td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">27</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">28</span></td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">29</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">30</span> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="rw-nine">
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">20</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">19</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">18</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">17</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">16</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">15</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">14</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">13</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">12</span></td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">11</span> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="rw-ten">
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">1</span></td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">2</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">3</span></td>
                                <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">4</span></td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">5</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">6</span></td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">7</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">8</span> </td>
                                <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">9</span> </td>
                                <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">10</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <section id="laddr-container">
                                <img src=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFLzI.png" class="lddr" id="lddr1">
                            </section>
                        </table>
  </div>
```

In the above code I'm trying to create a snake and ladder board. I need to be fix the ladder from 1 to 38. I tried to implement that  by setting different position property of ladder, but that didn't help me, which is varying according to screen change. Is anyone able to help me to fix this ladder from 1 to 38 in all windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use the image in background and update rotate and top values on resize.

**any html inside a table wich is not table elements can only be child of  cell or caption**

a quick example below

```js
// this average and might not be the wisest way to sort it out :)
function rotateit() {
  var ladder = document.getElementById('laddr-container');
  var tbwth = document.getElementById('rw-one').offsetWidth;
  var tbht = document.getElementById('rw-one').offsetHeight;
  var rtladr = (tbwth / tbht);
  ladder.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rtladr * 1.35 + 'deg)';
  ladder.style.top = tbht + rtladr + 'px';
}

window.onresize = rotateit;
window.onload = rotateit
```

```css
#board {
  width: 94%;
  height: 94%;
  border: .4rem solid #000;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1.7%;
  background-color: green;
  border: .4rem solid #000;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1.7%;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
tr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 ! important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.col {
  padding: 0 ! important;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  z-index: 890;
}
.odd {
  background-color: green;
}
.even {
  background-color: #fff;
}
/*#rw-one,#rw-three,#rw-five,#rw-seven,#rw-nine{
    /*width: 100%;
    height: 100%;*/

/*
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: red;
}*/

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}
.nmbr {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 7px yellow;
  margin-top: 26% ! important;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 34%;
  font-family: fantasy;
}
td,
tr {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
#rw-ten .nmbr {
  margin-left: 37%;
}
#laddr-container {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 2.5%;
  top: 10%;
  transform: rotate(34deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFLzI.png);
  width: 5%;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
table {
  position: relatve;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
  <table>

    <tr id="rw-one">
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">100</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">99</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">98</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">97</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">96</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">95</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">94</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">93</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">92</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">91</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rw-two">
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">81</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">82</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">83</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">84</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">85</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">86</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">87</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">88</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">89</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">90</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rw-three">
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">80</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">79</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">78</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">77</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">76</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">75</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">74</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">73</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">72</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">71</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rw-four">
      <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">61</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">62</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">63</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">64</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">65</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">66</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">67</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">68</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">69</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">70</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rw-five">
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">60</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">59</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">58</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">57</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">56</span>
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">55</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">54</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">53</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">52</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">51</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rw-six">
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">41</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">42</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">43</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">44</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">45</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">46</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">47</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">48</span>
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">49</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">50</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rw-seven">
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">40</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">39</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">38</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"> <span class="nmbr">37</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">36</span>
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">35</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">34</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">33</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">32</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">31</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rw-eight">
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">21</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">22</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">23</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">24</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">25</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">26</span>
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">27</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">28</span>
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">29</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">30</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rw-nine">
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">20</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">19</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">18</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">17</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">16</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">15</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">14</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">13</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">12</span>
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">11</span> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rw-ten">
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">1</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">2</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">3</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"> <span class="nmbr">4</span>
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">5</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">6</span>
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">7</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">8</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="even col"><span class="nmbr">9</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="odd col"><span class="nmbr">10</span>
        <section id="laddr-container">

        </section>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set id for each little box for exaple for 1 set id='b1', and for 38 id='b38'. Then use jquery to set the ladder style to this boxes:

```
var topOfb1=$('#b1').offset().top;
$(#laddr1).css('bottom', topOfb1);
var rightOfb1=$('#b1').offset().left+$('#b1').width();
$(#laddr1).css('left', rightOfb1');
```

and do this for bottom and left of 38 to set top and right of ladder.

And you can calculate the distance between 1 and 38 and set the width and height of ladder

Comment: Please remember the offset values are related to window not the table

Answer (score 0):

You can make the image positioned `absolute` and then just adjust the [responsive] distances and the rotation. For me it was

```
#lddr1{
    width: 3%;
    height: 39%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    left:13%;
    bottom: 1%;
}
```

See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls8wgz5c/14/).

Comment: if you resize your window you can sense that the ladder is moving,that is the actual problem